# The variable 'pos' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a bug in my code. How can I deal with it?

It can't compile successfully, but I can't find anything wrong.

## Day.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
typedef unsigned ud;
using std::string;
class Day
{
public:
    Day() = default;
    Day(string a) {
        decltype(a.size()) pos;
        if (a.find("Jan") != string::npos)
            month = 1;
        else if (a.find("Feb") != string::npos)
            month = 2;
        else if (a.find("Mar") != string::npos)
            month = 3;
        else if (a.find("Apr") != string::npos)
            month = 4;
        else if (a.find("May") != string::npos)
            month = 5;
        else if (a.find("Jun") != string::npos)
            month = 6;
        else if (a.find("Jul") != string::npos)
            month = 7;
        else if (a.find("Aug") != string::npos)
            month = 8;
        else if (a.find("Sep") != string::npos)
            month = 9;
        else if (a.find("Oct") != string::npos)
            month = 10;
        else if (a.find("Nov") != string::npos)
            month = 11;
        else if (a.find("Dec") != string::npos)
            month = 12;
        else {
            pos = a.find_first_not_of("123456789");
            month = stoi(a.substr(0, pos));
        }
        pos++;
        auto now = a.find_first_not_of("123456789", pos);
        day = stoi(a.substr(pos, now - pos));
        pos = now + 1;
        year = stoi(a.substr(pos, a.size() - pos));
    }
    ud get_year() {
        return year;
    }
    ud get_month() {
        return month;
    }
    ud get_day() {
        return day;
    }
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) {
        os << year << ' ' << month << ' ' << day;
        return os;
    }
private:
    ud year;
    ud month;
    ud day;
    bool iszm(char x) {
        return (x >= 'A'&&x <= 'z');
    }
};
```

## main.cpp

```cpp
#include"pch.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list>
#include<deque>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<array>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"Day.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Day tmp("March 27,2019");
    tmp.print(cout);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're using `pos` without it being initialized to a value first

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `x >= 'A'&&x <= 'z'` looks odd. If the code is supposed to be detecting a letter, use `std::isalpha`. If your system uses ASCII (which it almost certainly does), look up the value of the ASCII characters to see what the original expression actually does. If your system uses EBCDIC (the perennial problem child), `'z'` is less than `'A'`, and that expression will always be false.

Comment: @Pete Becke I understand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
else {
  pos = a.find_first_not_of("123456789");
  month = stoi(a.substr(0, pos));
}

pos++;  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

auto now = a.find_first_not_of("123456789", pos);
day = stoi(a.substr(pos, now - pos));
...
```

Once you get to the line `pos++;`, `pos` will have a known value only if the `else` clause above containing `pos = a.find_first_not_of("123456789");` has been executed and this happens only if `a` is different from `"Jan"`, `"Feb"`, etc.

Don't forget that local variables are not initialized to some default value but their initial content is indetermined.

Off topic: this code is really ugly and there may be more problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the benefits are great!

Comment: @Kdlyh that's a different question, but generally if you have code with  a repeated pattern of `if`s with only few changements there is usually a better way.

Comment: Understand, I am going to use map instead of duplicate if.

Comment: @Kdlyh yes, `std::map` is one possibility. Don't forget to make it `static` otherways the map will be populated on each and every call of the constructor

Comment: Okay, I understand.You have helped me a lot in my self-study!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   decltype(a.size()) pos;
>     if (a.find("Jan") != string::npos)
>         month = 1;
>     //    other else if statements removed
>     else {
>         pos = a.find_first_not_of("123456789");
>         month = stoi(a.substr(0, pos));
>     }
>     pos++;
> ```

In the above, I've removed a whole series of `else if` statements.

`pos` is defined and it is uninitialised.

If `a.find("Jan") != string::npos`   then `pos` is never assigned.   The next operation is `pos++` which retrieves the value of `pos` in order to increment it.   Since `pos` is unitialised, the behaviour is undefined.

In your code, the only place where `pos` is assigned a value in the series of `else if`s is in the final `else`.    Every other path through that code causes `pos++` to have undefined behaviour because - as your compiler is warning you - `pos` is uninitialised.

The way to fix the problem is to ensure that, no matter how the flow of execution occurs, `pos` is initialised before it is incremented.

One simple way to ensure that would be to change the definition to

```
decltype(a.size()) pos = 0;
```

Whether that is correct for your code, or not, depends on what you expect to happen in all the cases other than the final `else`.

Comment: Thank you,I wasn't serious at the time.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, but Jabberwocky answered earlier, so I adopted his answer, please understand

Answer (score 0):

## Thank you.I solved the problem.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
typedef unsigned ud;
using std::string;
class Day
{
public:
    Day() = default;
    Day(string a) {
        decltype(a.size()) pos=0;
        if (a.find("Jan") != string::npos)
            month = 1;
        else if (a.find("Feb") != string::npos)
            month = 2;
        else if (a.find("Mar") != string::npos)
            month = 3;
        else if (a.find("Apr") != string::npos)
            month = 4;
        else if (a.find("May") != string::npos)
            month = 5;
        else if (a.find("Jun") != string::npos)
            month = 6;
        else if (a.find("Jul") != string::npos)
            month = 7;
        else if (a.find("Aug") != string::npos)
            month = 8;
        else if (a.find("Sep") != string::npos)
            month = 9;
        else if (a.find("Oct") != string::npos)
            month = 10;
        else if (a.find("Nov") != string::npos)
            month = 11;
        else if (a.find("Dec") != string::npos)
            month = 12;
        else {
            pos = a.find_first_not_of("123456789");
            month = stoi(a.substr(0, pos));
        }
        pos = pos ? pos : a.find_first_not_of("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm");
        pos++;
        auto now = a.find_first_not_of("123456789", pos);
        day = stoi(a.substr(pos, now - pos));
        pos = now + 1;
        year = stoi(a.substr(pos, a.size() - pos));
    }
    ud get_year() {
        return year;
    }
    ud get_month() {
        return month;
    }
    ud get_day() {
        return day;
    }
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) {
        os << year << ' ' << month << ' ' << day;
        return os;
    }
private:
    ud year;
    ud month;
    ud day;
};
```